# Why does pinescript place orders two candles after a trigger condition

Tags: orders

I'm having some issues where my pinescript algo is placing orders two candles after my trigger conditions. My friends are also having the same issue. Does anyone know why this is the case and what I can do to solve it?

My code (I'm using HullMA as the trigger)

```
/////////////////Trend Indicator/////////////////

malength = input(defval=26, title="Moving Average Length", minval=1)
tsrc = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid),"15", close)

hullma(tsrc, len) =>
    hma = wma(2 * wma(tsrc, len / 2) - wma(tsrc, len), round(sqrt(len)))
    
zlema =hullma(tsrc, malength)
col =  zlema > zlema[1] ? color.green : color.red
plot(zlema,color=col, linewidth=4)

/////////////////Buy and Sell Orders/////////////////
//Order conditions
if col == color.green
    strategy.entry(id="long", long=true)
if col == color.red
    strategy.entry(id="short", long=false)
```

Problem:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, pinescript waits for candle closes and doesn't immediately initialise solutions, hence it takes two candles after the initial trigger before there is a signal